# Error in SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version f

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database, error-handling

I had to migrate my website to a new host. I have an invoice system which was programmed like 6 years ago, it works on older PHP version /5,4/ (if that can help for anything). I can access to the invoice system, but whenever I try to click on my invoices or clients a php error occures. This is the error:

Error Number: 1064

You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'rows FROM inv_client as t1 ORDER BY t1.firm asc' at line 1

SELECT COUNT(*) as rows FROM inv_client as t1 ORDER BY t1.firm asc

Filename: /home/dilys1/public_html/invoice/libraries/zcms/interfaces/interface_base.php

Line Number: 295

When i checked the filename and line number this is there:

```
    //Counting results
    $this->count_all = $this->db->query($count.$from.$join.$where.$order)->row()->rows;
    $this->count_results = count($this->raw_data);
```

I would appreciate any help. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

`rows` is a [reserved keyword in mysql](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/keywords.html).

use an other alias or add backticks around it

Comment: but it will not throw error.